# How can I permanently change the text size for gnome-terminal?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, gnome-terminal

I just wanted to ask...

It seems that you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (ctrl plus the minus sign) in order to get better resolution (smaller text) when running terminal.

But I was wondering if there was a way to do keep the settings this way, so that whenever you start up the terminal it will already be performing in higher resolution?

Answer (score 24):

You can manually set the size of the text in a terminal by :

1. opening a terminal
2. **Edit** -> **Profile Preferences**
3. select **Custom font** (or unselect **Use the system fixed width font** in older versions)
4. Choose your font and size

You can also choose the size of the terminal by selecting **Use custom default terminal size** and setting a number of rows and columns.

Comment: This is exactly what I do to get it permanently.

Comment: I don't see the "__Use the system fixed width font__" option in 16.04?

Comment: @rudolph9 have edited answer to say 'Select Custom Font' as that's what it says in my version (rather than 'use the system fixed wdth font')

Answer (score 6):

You can try to invoke `gnome-terminal` with parameter `--zoom`, e.g.:

`gnome-terminal --zoom=0.8` in order to zoom out 20% (80% of the original size)

Limited documentation for this parameter is found by running

```
gnome-terminal --help-all
```

You can play a bit with the different zoom sizes in order to find the appropriate one, and then edit your shortcuts accordingly.

Comment: Do you happen to know any way of setting a different default zoom? I can't find that in the settings, I can only change the zoom live, but then it reverts to 100%.